# Jquery to stylize only certain word from para

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stylize only certain word from my dynamic div

say,

```
<div id="info">{$info}</div> prints

<p>here you can get info about somnething. if you want more info about something then click here....</p>
```

I only want stylize the word **'info'**

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use jQuery to add styles to your HTML. You should generate proper HTML and then use CSS styling.

---

But if you still want to do this:

```
$("p").html( $("p").text().replace(/word/, "<span class='my-word'>word</span>") );
```

And in CSS:

```
.my-word { color: red; }
```